# Distance Sampling Code, getting error that I don't know how to fix

Tags: distance

I am running distance sampling and keep getting this error:

> Error in rep(0, dim(xmat)[1]) : invalid 'times' argument

I have tried changing the width and changing the layout of the data.

```
fi.mr.dist <- ddf(
    method='io.fi',
    mrmodel=~glm(link='logit',formula=~distance),
    data=detections,meta.data=list(width=107)
)
```

Comment: What language are you using? What does your data look like? What else have you  tried?

Comment: @BobDalgleish my data has the following columns: Study.Area, Observer.ID, Observer.Initials, Species, Individuals, distance, Date, Observer, Region.Label, Area, Sample.Label, MAS, HAS, Effort

Comment: Please edit your question with information required to ask for help. Information added in comments is difficult to read and is out of context.